# How to disconnect and reconnect in plsql procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am running a procedure in PL/SQL which has a `for loop`. I have a requirement wherein I need to disconnect and connect to the database after each iteration.

How can I accomplish this in the code, without manually disconnecting/connecting the database.

I am using PL/SQL developer.

Comment: Why do you have this requirement? What are you doing when disconnected? It might be better to do this in the database or do the database work through a shell script etc.

Comment: PL/SQL runs inside the database. How can you "disconnect" from that?

Comment: You cannot disconnect in a stored procedure. What is it that you **really** trying to do? Anything that involves disconnecting and connecting in a loop sounds like a horrible idea. My guess is that you don't really need that.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to create a new session, perhaps with DBMS_SCHEDULER?  Your main PL/SQL loop would have to stay connected, but it would spawn and close other sessions, which are pretty much the same thing as "connections".

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It is definitely not a normal requirement, which is why there is no simple solution.  So you need to explain your business requirement, and perhaps we can offer susggestions on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm then has to be implemented in the applicative layer, since pl/sql depends on a database connection.